# Pull Data from Google Sheets and display in HTML H3 tag

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I'm trying to pull data from Google Sheets and display in H3 tags which has specific IDs. Here's the link to my [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16vBfhbGUnmqw6kAFzLsmjWomOgzeV4a8hyX5U1fWjUY/edit#gid=0). I only want to pull Prices from that sheet and display within the H3 tags. How can I achieve this?

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
var temp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
temp.list = getValues();
return temp.evaluate();
}

function getValues() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ws = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var lastRow = ws.getLastRow();
var numRow = lastRow - 1;
return ws.getRange(2,1,numRow,2).getValues();
}
```

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>50-74 gallons: </h1><h3 id="firstPrice"></h3>
    <h1>74-99 gallons: </h1><h3 id="secondPrice"></h3>
    <h1>100-124 gallons: </h1><h3 id="thirdPrice"></h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the sheet values in a template variable (`list`), iterate through that variable, taking into account that it's a 2D array and that each inner array has two elements, corresponding to `Gallons` and `Price`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <? for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){ ?>
      <h1><?= list[i][0] ?></h1>
      <h3 id=<?= `price_${i+1}` ?>><?= list[i][1] ?></h3>
    <? } ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want each `h3` to have an `id` representing the index (as you wrote `firstPrice`), you could add the loop index to each `id`, for example as shown in the snippet above:

```
id=<?= `price_${i+1}` ?>
```

#### Important note:

Please note that this will only work for [Apps Script web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). The syntax `<?= ?>` is specifically designed for Apps Script, and will not work if you try it in another environment. See [scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets).

#### Edit:

If you don't want to use a loop, but to write the HTML elements manually, you would do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><?= list[0][0] ?></h1><h3 id="firstPrice"><?= list[0][1] ?></h3>
    <h1><?= list[1][0] ?></h1><h3 id="secondPrice"><?= list[1][1] ?></h3>
    <h1><?= list[2][0] ?></h1><h3 id="thirdPrice"><?= list[2][1] ?></h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry if I couldn't elaborate my concern perfectly. But basically I just want to grab the data let's say $3.09 from cell B2 and display between <h3 id="firstPrice">{{here}}</h3>

Also, I believe the following script should work to connect the spreadsheet? But it's giving me error in Google Chrome Console: net::ERR_ABORTED 404

<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/16vBfhbGUnmqw6kAFzLsmjWomOgzeV4a8hyX5U1fWjUY/1/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=onDataLoaded"></script>

Comment: @Obaid That's what this answer is doing, grabbing the data from column B2 and displaying it in the different `h3`. Can you please clarify this? Did you try this code? How's this not working for you?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working. Here is JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sh_obaid/40mpdyrh/4/

Comment: @Obaid Of course it will not work if you try it with pure JS. The template syntax (`<?= ?>`) is specifically Apps Script. You have to try it in an [Apps Script web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). I added a note to my answer explaining this.

Comment: oh sorry my bad. however, it's listing all of the data from the sheet. I only want to display prices in a particular h3 id. For example, <h3 id="firstPrice"></h3> this should display only data from B2 and <h3 id="secondPrice"></h3> this should display only data from B3.
Also, since it's working on WebApp. How can I integrate it in my Wordpress website?

Comment: Here is the Codepen link as well with some modifications: https://codepen.io/obaid-ullah-shaikh/pen/dyRMoEy

Comment: @Obaid `For example, <h3 id="firstPrice"></h3> this should display only data from B2 and <h3 id="secondPrice"></h3> this should display only data from B3` Yes, that's exactly what my suggested code is doing, but doing it in a loop and not manually writing each row, which arguably is not a best practice. Do you want to write the <h1> <h3>` rows manually instead? Also, have you tried if my answer works for you in Apps Script? Finally, integrating with Wordpress is a completely different question, I'd suggest to create new thread for that.

Comment: Yes, that's what exactly I'm trying to do, however if I add only <h3 id="firstPrice"></h3>  it's not showing any data. You can try having a look at the spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16vBfhbGUnmqw6kAFzLsmjWomOgzeV4a8hyX5U1fWjUY/) and AppScrip running [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwEY2gLaj5_an2nJD0P4Qb5HJtBDzmRBRipGG71cIYpKsGBLHJJbIEpyOz7a1Z3kbuGjQ/exec). Also, yes your code worked in App Script. I've temporarily commented out to test your next suggestion. Also, in Wordpress I'm using Plain HTML editor to integrate my data from spreadsheet.

Comment: @Obaid It's not showing any data because you are not providing any data for the `h3`. In order to add some server-side data to the template, wrap it with `<?= ?>` (e.g. `<h3 id="firstPrice"><?= SERVER_SIDE_DATA ?>`). Take a look at my updated answer (bottom section `Edit`). Also, as I said, this will only work for Apps Script web apps.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how can I implement this strategy in HTML however, it worked on App Script. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Even tho I found another way to pull data from Google Sheets and display on Website ..  However, your method worked like a charm for Web App . Thank you again for all your help!